# Calling php page from jquery in visual studio

Tags: php, jquery, visual-studio

I am trying to utilize the php code in ASP.NET, in one of the jquery (which is in JS folder) I have seen this method

```
$.get('somePage.php', {
                    text : text,
                    description : description
......
.....
```

Now, I have copied this page under my project

```
-Project
--Model
--Views
--Controller
--SomePage.php
etc
```

but it is not working.
However, the php code which I have downloaded is showing as following folder and file structure

```
-Images
-JS
-CSS
-SomePage.php
```

How can I call php page from this jquery in visual studio?

Comment: Are you running apache with php and iis with VS on the same computer?

Comment: No... Do I need to install xamp on my machine and everything then will work fine ?

Comment: However, I have installed this http://php-compiler.net/

Comment: You have to setup the apropiate environment to run php scripts...and you dont have to put the php file in your VS solution....you can call that file via ajax call ;)

Comment: Thanks.. I am installing http://php.iis.net/ to see if this can help

Comment: That seems to be a never ending story.. I would rather try to convert that into asp.net code or need to search freelancer to do that for me :(